# Mysql; Collect of real records

Tags: mysql

How do I get the number of records in MySQL table?

```
ID  fname   lname  
1   abc     qwe
3   asd     asd
4   dfsf    dfs
5   asd     asd
8   dfsf    dfs


Total Member (Total ID): 5
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of rows in a single table use `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM yourtable
```

See the manual page on [Counting rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/counting-rows.html).

Note that this requires a full table (or index) scan if you are using InnoDB.

From [InnoDB restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> InnoDB does not keep an internal count of rows in a table because concurrent transactions might “see” different numbers of rows at the same time. To process a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t` statement, InnoDB must scan an index of the table, which takes some time if the index is not entirely in the buffer pool. If your table does not change often, using the MySQL query cache is a good solution. To get a fast count, you have to use a counter table you create yourself and let your application update it according to the inserts and deletes it does. If an approximate row count is sufficient, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` can be used. See Section 13.2.13.1, “InnoDB Performance Tuning Tips”.

Comment: +1 for including a quote to the reference to show implications of using count().